# Saving model from REST adapter into localstorage

Tags: ember-data

Is there any easy way to save or copy an Ember model "from RESTAdapter to LSAdapter" (including relationships)?

For example like that?

```
var person = DS.RESTStore.find(Model.Person, 1);
DS.LSStore.createRecord(person);

DS.LSStore.commit();
```